# Create a loop device from partition image

Tags: dd, disk-image, loop-device

I have a `partition.img`. It was created with `dd if=/dev/sdb1 of=partition.img conv=noerror,sync`.

Now I want to have a loop device that: 1) has a GPT partition Table 2) its only partition is `partition.img`.

How to create that loop device?

Comment: `udisksctl loop-setup -f /path/to/your/img`

Comment: that mounts the image as the disk. I want the image to be a partition of the disk only